# Replace middle contents of NSString with other content

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have a string say for example "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h" , Now I want to replace content which is starting from index 4 & ending at index 6.

So in example the resulting string will be "a,b,c,d,f,e,g,h".

FYI only all the content in dynamic including the indexes to be replace..

I've no idea how to achieve this.. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: On what basis you'll decide start index and end index to be replaced?

Comment: @Rushi it is dynamic, I've a bunch of data & after filling it I'll have initial string & when I want to update that filled up data I have a temporary variable to decide at which index I need to update string using the temporary variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks from your example that you want to replace components in the string (i.e. index 4 is the fourth delimited letter - the 'e').  If that's the case, then the solution lies with NSString componentsSeparatedByString: and componentsJoinedByString:

```
// string is a comma-separated set of characters.  replace the chars in string starting at index
// with chars in the passed array

- (NSString *)stringByReplacingDelimitedLettersInString:(NSString *)string withCharsInArray:(NSArray *)chars startingAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    NSMutableArray *components = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];

    // make sure we start at a valid position
    index = MIN(index, components.count-1);

    for (int i=0; i<chars.count; i++) {
        if (index+i < components.count)
            [components replaceObjectAtIndex:index+i withObject:chars[i]];
        else
            [components addObject:chars[i]];
    }
    return [components componentsJoinedByString:@","];
}

- (void)test {
    NSString *start = @"a,b,c,d,e,f,g";
    NSArray *newChars = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"x", @"y", @"y", nil];
    NSString *finish = [self stringByReplacingDelimitedLettersInString:start withCharsInArray:newChars startingAtIndex:3];
    NSLog(@"%@", finish);  // logs @"a,b,c,x,y,z,g"

    finish = [self stringByReplacingDelimitedLettersInString:start withCharsInArray:newChars startingAtIndex:7];
    NSLog(@"%@", finish);  // logs @"a,b,c,d,e,f,x,y,z"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's better if you `NSMutableString`. See the following example:

```
int a = 6; // Assign your start index.
int b = 9; // Assign your end index.

NSMutableString *abcd = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"abcdefghijklmano"]; // Init the NSMutableString with your string.
[abcd deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(a, b)]; //Now remove the charachter in your range.

[abcd insertString:@"new" atIndex:a]; //Insert your new string at your start index.
```

Comment: why can't I use replaceCharactersInRange??

Comment: Yes you can replaceCharactersInRange as well. It'll do your task in one statement.